# How to get Timezone abbr for "Samoa" => "Pacific/Apia" in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, timezone

I am showing Timezone abbr on UI. It was working until I encountered "Samoa" => "Pacific/Apia" timezone data. The working code is,

```
tz_to_be_displayed = "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
start_time.in_time_zone(tz_to_be_displayed).strftime('%Z')
```

this code outputs "PDT", but when trying to get abbrfor "Samoa" it returns "+13"
I tried few things not worked. Let me know of anyone faced issue or know solution.